# Android App crashes when using .NET MAUI RelativeLayout

Tags: c#, android, xaml, maui

I am attempting to migrate a Xamarin.Forms app to .NET MAUI, however I have found that this bug also happens on a new .NET MAUI app.

The app that I am attempting to migrate over to .NET MAUI uses a RelativeLayout in a good number of its views, and whenever I attempt to run the app on an android device (I have no iOS devices to test this one, therefore I can't determine if it happens there), the app instantly crashes.

Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new .NET MAUI app using .NET 6.0 in Visual Studio 2022.
2. Replace the contents of the MainPage.xaml with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:cmp="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
             x:Class="Test_Maui_App.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <cmp:RelativeLayout>

        </cmp:RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

Replace the contents of MainPage.xaml.cs with the following:

```
namespace Test_Maui_App;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

3. Attempt to run the app on an android device with or without a debugger attached.
4. Observe the behavior of the app crash.

Looking in the device log in ADP doesn't provide any real useful information, unfortunately.

I'm aware that RelativeLayout is on its way out in favor of the other layouts that MAUI supports, but I was wondering if it would be possible for it to still be used (and save myself some time redoing a bunch of XAML lol).  If not, what's the best alternative?

Comment: what happens if you remove the `ScrollView` and/or add actual content to the `RelativeLayout`?  Does VS catch the unhandled exception?

Comment: Unfortunately, doing both of those still break the app, and no exception is thrown, actually.

Answer (score 1):

`AbsoluteLayout` and `RelativeLayout` have been moved to the Compatibility namespace. I tested the code you provided, and it crashed as you described. You can try to use Grid layout. In addition, you can check this: [RelativeLayoutPage](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/samples/Controls.Sample/Pages/Layouts/RelativeLayoutPage.xaml) by official code.

For more information, you can refer to [Announcing .NET MAUI Preview 7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-maui-preview-7/comment-page-4/#comments) by official blog.

You can also raise [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).